# I have problem with numpy slices when using scatter plot for showing all data. How can i fix it?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have NumPy array which data.shape showing (485,4) and i can`t plotting it with *plt.scatter*

```
array([[     20,       1,     263,  716693],
       [     74,      51,     107,  274393],
       [     27,       1,     165,  723841],...])

plt.scatter(data[:0],data[:,1],c=data[0:],cmap='rainbow')
```

I cant understand how can i slice it? I`m newbie can you help with plot it?

Comment: you're missing a comma here: `data[:0]`

Comment: i try to plot column 0

Comment: have you tried adding the comma?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to slice columns from numpy array. Here is the method. Hope it helps.

```
import numpy
test = numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
print( test[:,0])
```

**Output**

```
[1 3 5]
```

Here it accesses the first column. You can replace 0 with 1 and 2 to access the next column numbers.
If you want to access rows, here is the slicing method

```
print( test[0,:])
```

**Output**

```
[3 4]
```

It access first row of array.

Comment: why do we need 'from numpy import *'

Comment: You don't. Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my answer.  `from numpy import *` was unnecessary.